# processMessageFailed error when registering Android push notifications with ngCordova

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Because of some other application requirements I need to bootstrap angular. This has caused problems when registering android notifications using ngCordova [push notification](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/) ($cordovaPush).

I'm seeing a "processMessage failed: Error:"

```
processMessage failed: Error: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaPushProvider <- $cordovaPush
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.6/$injector/unpr?p0=%24cordovaPushProvider%20%3C-%20%24cordovaPush 
cordova.js:1059
processMessage failed: Stack: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaPushProvider <- $cordovaPush
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.6/$injector/unpr?p0=%24cordovaPushProvider%20%3C-%20%24cordovaPush
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:7888:12
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11806:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11953:39)
    at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11811:45
    at Object.getService [as get] (file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:11953:39)
    at eval (eval at processMessage (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1021:26), <anonymous>:1:75)
    at processMessage (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1021:13)
    at Function.androidExec.processMessages (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:1091:13)
    at pollOnce (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:956:17)
    at pollOnceFromOnlineEvent (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:946:5) 
cordova.js:1060
processMessage failed: Message: Jjavascript:angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]')).injector().get('$cordovaPush').onNotification({"regid":"APA91bEX-nZgrUPmxMxWKiIZpAi8zAaSgr58es6YXvaVk_wEffvm0pKPs-WNIxF-fTiYMxzxkZAxAul96ZxYVixWgSRs2VRn6NcTmPQXeQ7oXFghoL_Ya0cIbPLI1IQqOjPJzdVL974yV1A6VxFLwNHH1cjLkRp0-IIz6WaU4pHgImdOUD7HkOc","event":"registered"}) B
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed the trace and identified the line below as the culprit.

```
config.ecb = "angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]')).injector().get('$cordovaPush').onNotification";
```

The error is caused by `angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]'))` returning undefined.

A more correct way to access $injector in my case is to use this query (credit to [Ionic blog post](http://ionicframework.com/blog/angularjs-console/)):

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('html'))
```

There are two ways to solve this problem.

1. Change ng-cordova.js directly by editing the query.
2. Add an 'ecb' field to your config object. The value of the 'ecb' field should be `angular.element(document.querySelector('html')).injector().get('$cordovaPush').onNotification`

There is more information on this in an [issue forum](https://github.com/keshavos/generator-angularjs-cordova/issues/30). I found that none of the solutions presented worked for me until I found the above suggested query.

I'd love to see any additional solutions if there are any!